# How to complete FastAPI Google OAuth flow

Tags: python, security, google-oauth, fastapi

I followed the [official tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/) and was able to set up the security system for a username and password. But instead of (or in addition to) username and password, I want to set up a Google OAuth flow. For that I've followed this [blog post](https://blog.authlib.org/2020/fastapi-google-login) and [repo](https://github.com/authlib/demo-oauth-client/blob/master/fastapi-google-login/app.py), but I get to the `/auth/google` endpoint and don't know what to do next. That endpoint looks like this:

```
@app.get("/auth/google", response_model=None)
async def auth_via_google(request: Request) -> HTMLResponse | RedirectResponse:
    try:
        token: dict[str, Any] = await oauth.google.authorize_access_token(request)
    except OAuthError as error:
        return HTMLResponse(f"<h1>{error.error}</h1>")
    user: dict[str, Any] = token["userinfo"]
    # return dict(token)                         # blog post has it like this
    if user:                                     # repo does this
        request.session["user"] = dict(user)
    return RedirectResponse(url="/")
```

First of all, the blog post returns the `token` whereas the repo adds `user` to `request.session` and returns `RedirectResponse`. What's the difference and which should I use?

For context, the google side is properly set up because I am able to go through the OAuth consent screen and can even visualize the `token` as

```
{"access_token": <some_token>,"expires_in":3599,"scope":"openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile","token_type":"Bearer","id_token":<other_token>,"expires_at":1681411911,"userinfo":{"iss":"https://accounts.google.com", ... ,"sub":<some_number>,"email":"me@gmail.com","email_verified":true, ... ,"name":"Me Myself", ... ,"exp":1681411914}}
```

This [article](https://nilsdebruin.medium.com/fastapi-google-as-an-external-authentication-provider-3a527672cf33) mentions swapping google's token for my own but do I need to do that or does my flow end at `/auth/google`?

The official FastAPI tutorial makes you create some functions (`authenticate_user`, `create_access_token`, `get_current_user`, and `get_current_active_user`), as well as the `/token` endpoint. Is any of that still needed when using google oauth?

If I try to redirect to eg. `/home` and `/home` is protected by the original tutorial's user and password system, I am currently getting an `Unauthorized` error.

Should `/auth/google` actually redirect to the `/token` endpoint I had set up in the tutorial? How can I replace (or integrate with) this new google flow with my existing user and password security system?